# How do I make a correct curvefit of an exponential function?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting

In an experiment I measured the voltage (V) and the current (I) through a diode to eventually calculate the Boltzmann constant.

The results are an exponential function following from the relation I = a(e^(bV)-1).

When I created a curvefit through my measurements, with the y-axis (I) on a logarithmic scale, it didn't to through them at all.
This is my code:

```
V=np.array([0.015,0.060,0.108,0.162,0.214,0.268,0.313,0.351,0.381,0.417,0.455,0.517,0.545,0.582,0.604])
I=np.array([0.0200,0.0800,0.2000,0.6200,1.6900,4.8400,11.5800,24.5000,44.3400,90.4000,183.3000,505.5000,744.3800,1149.0500,1346.6000])/1000000

def func(x,a,b,c):
    y = a*(np.exp(b*x)-1)
    return y

popt,pcov = curve_fit(func,V,I,p0=[3.651e-9,19.77])

V_cf = np.linspace(np.min(V),np.max(V),1000)
I_cf = func(V_cf,*popt)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(V,I,'k.', label='Measurements')
plt.plot(V_cf,I_cf,'m--',linewidth=1)
plt.xlabel("$V$ (V)")
plt.ylabel("$I$ (A)")
plt.yscale('log')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

How do I make it go through my measured points properly in my plot?
And why does the curvefit not become a straight line in my plot with y on a logarithmic scale?

my plot of my measurements and the curvefit
[image: my plot of my measurements and the curvefit]

improved plot by adding `p0=[3.651e-9,19.77]`
[image: improved plot by adding p0=[3.651e-9,19.77]]

Comment: Would you be able to share the data? Or at least, a plot of the experimental data?

Comment: You should provide an initial guess for the parameters using the `p0` argument of `curve_fit`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO!, can you please provide more details about the code you used ?

Comment: How many trials/measurements did you have in your experiment? (i.e. how large V & I are). Could be that there are too few points.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I have added my code and the plot it gives me. The arrays at the top are my measurements, where V is the voltage in Volts and I the current in micro-A, converted to A by dividing by 1 000 000.

Comment: One likely issue is that the data with small values (low current, low voltage) contribute less to the chi^2 than those with larger values. Hence a chi^2 fit will optimise towards the larger values, which is what you see: the four largest values are fitted reasonably well. You would either need a different type of optimisatation (non-chi^2), or better: fit V vs the log of I. So that your exponential function becomes basically linear.

Comment: [cont] The results when plotted back on a log scale like here, however, may be similar, since the deviation for lower values will show exaggerated on this plot anyway. But perhaps there is actually some experimental offset for low voltages, that isn't modelled properly by your function.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand why the function doesn't fit well then. Because there is a larger uncertainty in the larger values of I and V, but those also contribute more as you explained, so it is probably a problem in my data.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not working, because your function takes three parameter `a`, `b` and `c` (although `c` is not used) but you give only two initial guesses via the `p0` argument to `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

Aside from that, you cannot expect the function $f(x) = a (\exp{-bx} - 1)$ to become a straight line in an y-log-plot because of the $-1$. When taking the logarithm of both sides, you get $\log{f} = \log{\exp{-bx} - 1} + log{a}$ which does not resemble the form of a straight line, $y = mx + c$. Removing the $-1$ will give you a straight line with slope $-b$ and intercept $\log{a}$: $\log{f} = -bx + \log{a}$.

Does the following code do what you want?

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

voltage = np.array([0.015, 0.060, 0.108, 0.162, 0.214, 0.268, 0.313, 0.351, .381, 0.417, 0.455, 0.517, 0.545, 0.582, 0.604])
current = np.array([0.0200, 0.0800, 0.2000, 0.6200, 1.6900, 4.8400, 11.5800, 24.5000, 44.3400, 90.4000, 183.3000, 505.5000, 744.3800, 1149.0500, 1346.6000]) / 1e6

def fexp(x, a, b):
    return a * np.exp(b * x)

def fexp_yshift(x, a, b):
    return a * (np.exp(b * x) - 1)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fexp, xdata=voltage, ydata=current, p0=[3.651e-9, 19.77])
popt_shift, pcov_shift = curve_fit(fexp_yshift, xdata=voltage, ydata=current, p0=[3.651e-9, 19.77])

x = np.linspace(np.min(voltage), np.max(voltage), 1000)
fit = fexp(x, *popt)
fit_shift = fexp_yshift(x, *popt_shift)

plt.plot(voltage, current, "k.", label="Measurement")
plt.plot(x, fit, "m--", label="Model")
plt.plot(x, fit_shift, "c-.", label="Model with Shift")
plt.xlabel("Voltage $V$ / V")
plt.ylabel("Current $I$ / A")
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()

plt.plot(voltage, current, "k.", label="Measurement")
plt.plot(x, fit, "m--", label="Model")
plt.plot(x, fit_shift, "c-.", label="Model with Shift")
plt.xlabel("Voltage $V$ / V")
plt.ylabel("Current $I$ / A")
plt.yscale('log')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Sorry that I don't know how to add math formulas to Stack Overflow posts.

**EDIT**: I just realized that this does not answer how to improve the quality of the fit. To get a better fit, fit the logarithm of the current directly by a straight line:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

voltage = np.array([0.015, 0.060, 0.108, 0.162, 0.214, 0.268, 0.313, 0.351, .381, 0.417, 0.455, 0.517, 0.545, 0.582, 0.604])
current = np.array([0.0200, 0.0800, 0.2000, 0.6200, 1.6900, 4.8400, 11.5800, 24.5000, 44.3400, 90.4000, 183.3000, 505.5000, 744.3800, 1149.0500, 1346.6000]) / 1e6
current_log = np.log10(current)

def line(x, m, c):
    return m * x + c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(line, xdata=voltage, ydata=current_log)
fit = line(voltage, *popt)

plt.plot(voltage, current_log, "k.", label="Measurement")
plt.plot(voltage, fit, "m--", label="Model")
plt.xlabel("Voltage $V$ / V")
plt.ylabel("Logarithmic Current $\log{(I / \mathrm{A})}$")
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]